# Flex- change position of child's child?

Tags: html, css

I wish to get A to sit at the top, B to sit in the middle and C to sit at the bottom.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axyLvemm/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="sub-container">
        <div class="b">B</div>
        <div class="c">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

i need to keep the same markup - how can I change the position of a div that is not the immediate child of the flex container?

EDIT:

It should look like this

A

B

C

Comment: What do you mean by top, middle, and bottom (alignment or order)?  And what is your reasoning for using a sub-container?

Comment: I need to use a sub container for mobile version of nav

Comment: Also, I mean alignment, A should be at the top, B in the middle etc.

Comment: ive updated teh question with what it should look like

Comment: The edit is also not very clear. The arrangement is already top-middle-bottom!

Comment: Check the fiddle - it is not top middle bottom.

Comment: The reason they are spaced as your fiddle shows is that your container is 100% height and flexbox uses space-between content justification.  You would have to set heights for a, b, and c in order to justify their content within.  Can you provide an image?

Comment: See here -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/axyLvemm/2/ Is this what you mean? Your sub-container is not flexed. Even if it were, the two children would be distributed and then the two sub-children within their respective parents. This will not provide a uniform distribution.

Comment: Close, but B is not centered.

Comment: @panthro: This is what I meant -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/axyLvemm/5/ Compare this to the earlier fiddle you will get the idea and the problem there.

Comment: You could use height percentages relative to number of nav elements: https://jsfiddle.net/axyLvemm/6/.  Getting warmer?

Comment: No, height needs to be dependent on dynamic content

Comment: *"height needs to be dependent on dynamic content"* -- @panthro, you do understand what is flex don't you? If your content is dynamic and you want to keep heights based on the content, then what is the problem with the first fiddle that I shared above?? See here the same one with content -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/axyLvemm/7/

Comment: Flexboxes apply only to immediate children so it won't work the way you want if the number of grandchildren is dynamic.  This may be a job for JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS Display Module Level 3 introduces [`display: contents`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-contents):

> The element itself does not generate any boxes, but its children and
>   pseudo-elements still generate boxes as normal. For the purposes of
>   box generation and layout, the element must be treated as if it had
>   been replaced with its children and pseudo-elements in the document
>   tree.

You can use it to "ignore" the subcontainer, and display all the inner items as if they belonged to the same container.

```css
body { margin: 0 }
.container {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
.sub-container {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's not widely supported yet, though.

Comment: "It's not widely supported yet, though." so useless then?

Comment: @panthro It's not useless. If somebody in two years or so has the same problem, he will be able to use it. I don't answer to fix the problem specifically for you, I answer to help the community.

Comment: I would point out that  (I think) this will still not **center** the middle element if the others are not the same height. There is no mechanism to guarantee that a specific flex item will be dead center.

Comment: @Paulie_D True, this will make B equidistant from A and C, but won't necessarily place it at the middle of the flex container. Given `justify-content: space-between`, I assumed this was the desired behavior.

Comment: Oh...your answer is great...I just wanted to clarify since I have a feeling that's what the OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

With this HTML code where `.b` and `.c` aren't siblings of `.a`, you can achieve desired result with a *flex inception*: `.sub-container` is both a flex item of parent `.container` and a flex container for `.b` and `.c`

`flex: 2 0 auto;` is related to height ratio of 1/3 + **(1/3 + 1/3)**

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o01p7w4y/)

```css
.container{
display: flex; 
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
}
.sub-container {
flex: 2 0 auto;
/* flex inception */
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
background-color: lightgreen;
}
.a, .b, .c {
flex: 1 0 auto; /* .a and .b, .c are not flex items of the same parent though we still want the same value */
padding: 1rem 0;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color: blue;">
  <div class="a" style="background-color: red;">A</div>
  <div class="sub-container" style="background-color: green;">
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want them to be equal heights, they should be the height of their contents.

Comment: More like this: https://jsfiddle.net/o01p7w4y/1/ ? B isn't exactly centered, its top is at 50% of visible height and you probably want its center to be well centered?